# Delegate between UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have following structure of ViewControllers:

[image]

PageViewController contains PhotoViewController and VideoViewController, that changing programmatically, so there no any segues.

I want allow VideoControlViewController to use methods from CameraViewController. I tried to use following code:

```
self.videoControlViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoControlViewController"];
self.videoControlViewController.delegate = self;
```

It don't works because method "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" creates new instance of VideoViewController. Here is topic with the same problem that I found:

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/109543-string-becomes-nil-after-viewdidload-with-protocol-and-delegate.html

How can I point self.VideoControlViewController to its instance from storyboard if there no any segues or transitions?

---

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    self.viewControllers = @[@"photoControlViewController", @"videoControlViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    [[self.pageViewController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[self viewControllerAtIndex:[self.viewControllers indexOfObject:@"photoControlViewController"]]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageViewController view]];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

Comment: What object owns (or creates or has a reference to) your original instance of `VideoControlViewController`?

Comment: It created with storyboard, but not connected with other ViewControllers. Added screenshot and code sample.

Comment: In this case, I think `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` should work fine because you don't have any other instance in memory.  (What you have in the storyboard is basically a template that only becomes an instance when something causes that to happen.)

Comment: It dont works. Delegate method not being called and .delegate property in VideoControlViewController is nil. So there is instance of VideoControlViewController that created by PageViewController.